# BulletDecorator with TextBlock not showing Unicode character

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, unicode, textbox

Any ideas why this doesn't work as expected?
At runtime the output of our WPF app literally shows the `\u2022` sequence.. while I'd expect the bullet point character ([Unicode Character 'BULLET' (U+2022)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm)):

```
    <BulletDecorator VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBlock Text="\u2022"/>
        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBoxStyle}" 
             TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
             Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </BulletDecorator>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind - the following formatting works:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x2022;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can put directly your bullet in the text :

```
<TextBlock Text="•"  />
```